# Bash: Reposition substring within a string

Tags: regex, bash, unix, awk, sed

I have some files which I would like to rename. The filenames look like below:

```
C18-02B-NEB-sktrim_1-20000000.fq
C18-02B-NEB-sktrim_1-30000000.fq
C18-02B-NEB-sktrim_1-50000000.fq
C18-02B-NEB-sktrim_2-20000000.fq
C18-02B-NEB-sktrim_2-30000000.fq
...
```

I would like to reposition the `_digit` part to before `.fq` like so.

```
C18-02B-NEB-sktrim-20000000_1.fq
C18-02B-NEB-sktrim-30000000_1.fq
C18-02B-NEB-sktrim-50000000_1.fq
C18-02B-NEB-sktrim-20000000_2.fq
C18-02B-NEB-sktrim-30000000_2.fq
...
```

I am able to capture my substring of interest as such:

```
find  * | egrep -o '_[0-9]'
_1
_1
_1
_2
_2
```

I could also remove the substring from the string as such:

```
find  * | sed 's/_[0-9]//'
C18-02B-NEB-sktrim-20000000.fq
C18-02B-NEB-sktrim-30000000.fq
C18-02B-NEB-sktrim-50000000.fq
C18-02B-NEB-sktrim-20000000.fq
```

but I am not sure how to move it over to the new position and then rename the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
find . -name '*.fq' -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "$(echo "$0" |sed "s/^\(.*\)\(_[0-9]\)\(.*\)\.fq$/\1\3\2.fq/")"' {} \;
```

`sed` part:

```
sed "s/^\(.*\)\(_[0-9]\)\(.*\)\.fq$/\1\3\2.fq/"
```

Explanation:

`find . -name '*.fq'` searches for the glob pattern `*.fq` and then the `-exec` option executes a `mv` command per each file found.

The `sh -c 'mv "$0" "$var"' {}` construct is just a `mv` command with two arguments and `$0` is substituted with `{}` which is the filename found by `find`

---

If file renaming is all you want, better use tools that are exclusively for file renaming though. rename is a pretty popular tool to do this kind of stuff, but I got my own tool: [rnm][1].

With [rnm](https://github.com/neurobin/rnm), you can do:

```
rnm -rs '/^(.*)(_\d)(.*)\.fq$/\1\3\2.fq/' *.fq
```

<del>Or using the exact same regex like the `sed` command (i.e BRE):</del> BRE support was dropped in favor of PCRE2.

Answer (score 2):

Use capture groups, e.g.:

```
 sed 's/\(.*\)sktrim\(_[0-9]*\)\(.*\)\.fq/\1sktrim\3\2.fg/'
```

The [rename](http://www.unix.com/man-page/Linux/1/rename/) perl utility can turn this sed expression and a set of files into a set of corresponding `mv`'s.
Since those rename-generated `mv`'s will be at the system level (they won't launch `/bin/mv` but rather just use the [rename(2)](http://www.unix.com/man-page/Linux/2/rename/) system function) it'll be faster than using generating your own `mv` commands and launching them from the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Using `rename`

```
rename 's/sktrim(_\d+)(.*)\.fq/sktrim$2$1.fq/' *.fq
```